# JavaScript, how do I make fill() a variable (that I can use in a custom function)?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, arguments, fill

I'm new to JS and have not found an answer to this question (or any question like it). I'm making a relatively simple program: create fish in tank and have them be of different lengths and colour.

I can make them different lengths through having a length variable in the parameters and editing the length argument within the function, but I do not think that same logic can be applied to custom adjustable colours in the same way*.

So in essence, how would I structure my code so that I can create the command *fill()*, a variable such that it can be edited to make different colours from the function call?

*EDIT: Apologies, I forgot to add code:

```
background(147, 226, 250);

var colour = fill(158, 52, 158); //Failed attempt at custom fill()

var drawFish = function(posX, posY, x) {

  ellipse(posX, posY, 166, 31);
  triangle(posX + 81, posY, posX + 125, posY - 16, posX + 125, posY + 16);
  ellipse(posX - 60, posY - 1, 10, 10);

};
drawFish(90, 241);
drawFish(121, 174);
drawFish(175, 356);
drawFish(238, 300);
drawFish(263, 22);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You might want to include a sample of the code you're trying.

Comment: Sure, this is very doable. I find it's often easiest to use the HSL color system to do so. For example `'hsl(' + 360 * Math.random() + ', 80%, 55%)'` but replace the random with the function argument (value between 0 and 1).

Comment: *EDIT: Thanks for answering quickly!

@ZachSaucier
That's interesting, wasn't aware of other colour schemes. Is there a place where I can find out more about HSL? This is the first I'm hearing of it.
I have a hard time understanding that line of code (except the Math.random() ), care to explain?

Comment: Found out about colour systems, the above is covered. What I'm confused about is the math inside the 'hsl' function.

Comment: What canvas library are you using?

Comment: @ZachSaucier
I'm not sure, I'm on KhanAcademy (an educational website) and they provide a section to write code and a section where it displays the result of that code (no further information).
All I've heard from comments is that the presence of the draw () function means something like ProcessingJS is 'active'? Didn't know what that meant unfortunately (I'm only familiar with importing Java libraries like Scanner and util).

Comment: Cool. So try to set up a minimal demo using something like JSFiddle or CodePen that loads ProcessingJS and recreates your situation. Then edit your question to include that demo.

Comment: Went on JSFiddle, added the ProcessingJS framework/extension and more of my code, as I had multiple fish.

Comment: It says both background() and fill() is not defined.

"<a class='gotoLine' href='#26:1'>26:1</a> ReferenceError: background is not defined"
"<a class='gotoLine' href='#26:14'>26:14</a> ReferenceError: fill is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

ANSWERED!
I couldn't make fill() a variable of course but instead I created variables that would generate random numbers from 0 to 256(exclusive) and placed them inside the fill() function. This allowed me to generate different colours for my fish!

Thanks for the help.

Sample code:

```
var drawFish = function (posX, posY, tailSize) {
    
    stroke(74, 74, 74);
    var randomNum = random(0,256);
    var randomNum1 = random(0,256);
    var randomNum2 = random(0, 256);
    
    fill(randomNum, randomNum1, randomNum2); 
    var bodySize = random(150, 200);
    ellipse (posX, posY, 166,31); //body
    
    
    fill(randomNum1, randomNum, randomNum2);
    triangle (posX + 81, posY, posX + 125/20*tailSize, posY - 16/20*tailSize, posX + 125/20*tailSize, posY+16/20*tailSize); //tail
    
    //...(Removed code)
  
};
```